# Can't connect to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run EC2 instance on AWS but after creating when I do ssh from gibash or any thing else it says time out.

First I think it was some error through my end but it wasn't I disable the firewall etc.

But when I open the public ip address after giving the permission to 80 port from all ip address the webpage open and says it took too much time to respond.

So I clicked on my created instance and pressed **Connect** from the header and tried to connect direct from AWS (to open console) but the error is still displaying.

I tried with different Operating Systems:

- Amazon  Linux
- Ubuntu
- Centos 7

Comment: check the security groups on the instance, do you have the port 80 and 22 (for ssh) open? Does the instance have a public IP? When you do a screenshot of the instance console, what do you see? Did you provide any user data or you just use an existing image with no custom scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Typical things to check when trying to connect to an EC2 instance:

#### Security Groups

Check that at least one of the Security Groups associated with the instance has port 22 (SSH) or port 3389 (RDP) open to your source IP range (eg a specific IP address 54.87.23.11/32, or the whole world 0.0.0.0/0 -- the latter is very poor security practice but worth trying to see if it helps). Security Groups are stateful, so you only need to open **Inbound** access and the return path will automatically work.

#### Public IP Address

Confirm that you are using a Public IP address associated with the instance. This can either be assigned at instance launch (which will allocate a random IP address from a pool) or can be assigned as an Elastic IP Address (which is a static IP address that you can assign assign to any instance and you keep it until you release it back to AWS).

#### Public Subnet / Routing

Confirm that your instance is in a "Public" VPC Subnet. This means that the Route Table associated with the Subnet has a route through an Internet Gateway.

#### Your Network

If you are connecting via a corporate network, be aware that some companies block SSH access via their network. Try to connect via a different network (eg home, office, tethered via your phone).